# Check if exists empty value between valid values

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a code to check if an array has empty values between valid values or before them.

At first I tried to use array_filter to remove empty values and then check if the remaining indexes of the valid values are consecutives, but I think there might be a simple way.

Here are examples

These array are processed as VALID

```
Array =>
  0 => string '030208000000000'
  1 => string ''
  2 => string ''

Array =>
  0 => string '030208000000000'
  1 => string '030210700000000'
  2 => string ''
```

These array are processed as NOT VALID

```
Array =>
  0 => string '030208000000000'
  1 => string ''
  2 => string '030210500000000'

Array =>
  0 => string ''
  1 => string '030208000000000'
  2 => string '030210500000000'
```

Comment: To check if the values are consecutives, you can compare it to `array_values($yourFilteredArray)`. How are you doing it now?

Comment: was actually subtracting each index and the next to check if the difference is 1 :b

Comment: A bit confused. Empty values should be consecutive for `not valid`?

Comment: Then you should probably use `$yourFilteredArray === array_values($yourFilteredArray)`

Comment: Let me try to do

Comment: @jeroen, it worked! Wanna post an answer so I can upvote?

Comment: is `['', '']` supposed to be valid ?

Comment: Hello Cid! It's supposed to be invalid. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a good old loop with flags to check if you already found empty.

```
function IsArrayValid($MyArray)
{
    $EmptyFound = false;
    $NonEmptyFound = false;
    foreach ($MyArray as $value)
    {
        if ($value !== '') // we found something non empty
        {
            $NonEmptyFound = true;
            if ($EmptyFound) // we already found something empty before.
            {
                // array is invalid
                // we can leave the loop and the function now
                return false;
            }
        }
        else // we found something empty
        {
            $EmptyFound = true;
        }
    }
    // looks like we didn't find anything invalid
    // return the value of $NonEmptyFound to make sure that an array with only empty value
    // will be invalid
    return $NonEmptyFound;
}

$ValidArray1 = array('foo', '', '');
$ValidArray2 = array('foo', 'bar', '');
$InvalidArray3 = array('foo', '', 'bar');
$InvalidArray4 = array('', '', 'foo');

echo "array 1 is valid ? " . (IsArrayValid($ValidArray1) ? "yes" : "no") . PHP_EOL;
echo "array 2 is valid ? " . (IsArrayValid($ValidArray2) ? "yes" : "no") . PHP_EOL;
echo "array 3 is valid ? " . (IsArrayValid($InvalidArray3) ? "yes" : "no") . PHP_EOL;
echo "array 4 is valid ? " . (IsArrayValid($InvalidArray4) ? "yes" : "no") . PHP_EOL;
```

Output :

```
array 1 is valid ? yes
array 2 is valid ? yes
array 3 is valid ? no
array 4 is valid ? no
```

Comment: Note that the comment you posted below the other answers also applies to your answer as you are using `!=` instead of `!==` in your comparison :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the examples you give, it looks as though the only valid lists are ones where the array has values from the start and only empty values at the end.

Assuming this, this uses the `array_filter()` to remove empty items and then compares the remaining keys against a simple `range()` from 0 to the number of remaining elements-1...

```
$a = [ '030208000000000', '', '' ];
// $a = [ '030208000000000', '030210700000000', '' ];
// $a = [ '', '030208000000000', '030210500000000' ];
// $a = [ '030208000000000', '', '030210500000000' ];

$b = array_filter($a);
if ( array_keys($b) == range(0, count($b)-1)) {
    echo "valid";
}
else    {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

If you need to ensure that '0' is counted as valid, you can alter the filter to be

```
$b = array_filter($a, function ($val) { return $val !== ''; });
```

Comment: Note that `[ '0', '030208000000000', '030210500000000' ];` will be considered as **invalid**

Comment: @Cid added alternative use of filter if required.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter your array to get rid of the empty values, you can compare the resulting array with that same array with all its keys reindexed using `array_values`.

So your check would be:

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($originalArray);
if ($filteredArray === array_values($filteredArray)) {
    // all consecutive values / valid input
}
```

Comment: Note that `[ '0', '030208000000000', '030210500000000' ];` will be considered as **invalid**

Comment: @Cid True, but as the OP is already using `array_filter` that would seem to be a given; the question is about consecutive keys as far as I can see.

Comment: I know, but OP stated *empty values*, not *falsy values*